# How to bind one page to several pages

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have several buttons that all enter one page.

How do I tell that page which button called it?

And can a page be bind to multiple pages or multiple tables in a database?

I actually have several lists of API that I do not want to for each create a separate page for. I want to create a page and show all the lists in one page, but separately.

That is, if I have 10 lists of  20 items, each 20 items should be displayed separately, not 200 items together!

Can I do this?

Thanks to those who guide me!

Comment: What have you done so far? a minimum of sample code for clarification will be appreciated.

Comment: I could only bind a list! Is there a conventional method? @Cfun

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  You're asking multiple different questions in a single post, and the questions are pretty broad and vague without any concrete code to illustrate what you're working on.

Comment: If you are careful, the goal of the two questions is the same! @Jason

Comment: "How do I tell that page which button called it?" - pass a parameter to the page when calling it?

Comment: I  have several lists of API that I do not want to for each create a separate page for. I want to create a page and show all the lists in one page, but separately. @Jason

Comment: are you asking "how do I create a page that can show the results of one of 10 different API calls based on a parameter"?

Comment: Yes ! And then I want show the results of those different calls  separately! @Jason

Comment: That was not at all clear from the question you posted.  Does each API call return the same model, or do they each have different return types?

Comment: Returns a model but with different inputs that will have different results! @Jason

Comment: do you want your page to have 10 different ListViews and only one is shown based on a parameter, or just one ListView that shows the results of the selected API call?

Comment: I want to have a  list view, but with different calls and each call I specified, the list  view information changes! @Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for each button click, pass a parameter to the page

```
void ButtonClickX(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
  Navigation.PushAsync(new ListPage("somevalue"));
}
```

then in your page constructor

```
string PageType;

void ListPage(string pageType)
{
  PageType = pageType;
}

override void OnAppearing()
{
  switch (PageType)
  {
     case "Value1":
       MyListView.ItemsSource = await APICall1();
       break;
     case "Value2":
       MyListView.ItemsSource = await APICall2();
       break;
     ...
  }
}
```